# How use Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork field to represent minutes?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, burndowncharts

According to description of Remaining Work field available here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-numeric?view=azure-devops#fields-used-to-estimate-and-track-work I set my ProcessConfiguration with "h" for hours.

Since Remaining Work is declared as double, I guess that is possible to enter in this field hours but also minutes. Is it ok to set "half an hour" with 0.5? "10 minutes" with 0,16 and so on?

Comment: You can set "half an hour" as 0.5, that's right. For my point of view, it is not useful to get lower than 0.5hour to break down activities, otherwise you might take more to track them rather than to develop them

Comment: If you're trying to track work by the *minute*, there is serious micromanagement going on. Reconsider that desire. You're not going to get useful data and the developers are going to hate it because time tracking at that level of granularity is a major waste of time.

Comment: Ok I agree with you that micro managing of Task is a waste of time. My question was intended to trace some support tasks for final users (therefore not a scrum/agile use of TFS according literature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could track it like that.  I think if you try to track individual times less than a quarter hour it brings on a lot of other problems though.  If you have multiple people working on the same task, the out-of-box functionality is not great for tracking that.  If you want to roll-up tasks time to a feature or PBI, the roll-up is not that great.

I've worked on projects that were billable to different customers and we billed in quarter-hour increments.  We tracked the time for billing and used a paid extension, [Timetracker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=7pace.Timetracker).  It was good at managing to the level of detail you might desire based on the wording in your question.